# What's the meaning behind the rarity item's classified in Anime/manga?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

In anime, i always seen some item rarity that classified like

- S (super)
- SS (super super (?) ) maybe... i dont know

and many alphabetic words. Why did they add like "S" for super on the classified of rarity item like that ? Why they dont use like "A+","A-","B+" just like score result of an exam ? What is the story behind it ? What's the first anime/literature that used this kind of method ?

Ex. [Classified Greed island Card Rarity in Hunter x Hunter](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Greed_Island_Card_Lists#List_of_the_40_Spell_Cards)

Comment: R, SR, and SSR/UR (their exact definition can vary between games) are specific to gatcha games in general and have no bearing on anime and manga in particular. HxH's Greed Island arc uses SS-H for card rarity limits. Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70673/in-some-games-the-rank-above-a-is-s-what-does-s-represent Theses are two similar but unrelated concepts.

Comment: thnaks for the explanation @кяαzєя

Comment: This isn't specific to item rarity; in _One-Punch Man_ the hero rankings go from A to S as well, and outside anime you have chocobo rankings in _Final Fantasy VII_ doing the same.

Comment: They do use +/- in some settings, such as Lyrical Nanoha's mage ranks (they still have S, SS, and SSS ranks there, and the +/- apply to them as well), or for stats, skills and Noble Phantasm ranks on the Fate series (they don't have S rank, but instead it's called EX rank when it's beyond measurement). In the end, it's just the author choice how to rank items, skills, etc. They could rank them Normal, Magic, Rare, Epic, Legendary like some games do and it wouldn't matter if it's what the author wants.

Answer (score 4):

It not generally used in reallife. It is originally come from Japanese Animation & Games, is generally come from games. In real life school ranking mark only A, B, C is credit marks, this will feel not enough for high ranking. In Games, is freely to input A+, A-, B+, B- rank system, but games generally put on SSS, SS, S, A, B, C, D, E, F, make players feel more happy on their result.

It means Super or Superior or alike surprise. Superlative classification. Super x3, Super x2, is weird to put Sx2, Sx3, so it is SSS, SS.

Some of games you can see R, SR, SSR, UR. R is meaning "Rare", mostly in card games. That means you get a rare card. SR is Super Rare. SSR is Specially Super Rare sometimes. UR is Ultimate Rare.

[Rare[R]Super Rare[SR] Card Sample](http://www.dbs-cardgame.com/cardlist/?search=true&category=428001&rarity=Super%20Rare[SR]) , [Ultimate Rare[UR] Card sample](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Ultimate_Rare_cards)

**Edit**

I remember I learned about this game s-ranking system, but I don't remember who is the author of making this system, sorry. I remember have origin author who make this s-rank, but not remember the name, this is minor title in history. 
Such as statement "The atom bomb S-Ranked Hiroshima" from Urban Dictionary: S-Rank. And, SS-Rank is by The early rank system of 1926, insignia of the Schutzstaffel. Early military.

Information is here:
   [Giant Bomb: S-Rank](https://www.giantbomb.com/s-rank/3015-2962/),
[S-Rank_Japanese](https://www.reddit.com/r/truegaming/comments/6cav1j/s_rank_origin_in_japanese/)

Comment: any reference ? for make your answer more acceptable.
reference,journal,literature,etc.

Comment: I studied this at college, university.

Comment: eh ? what kind of subject did you studied ? 
i have upvoted your answer, but maybe i will wait for another answer.

Comment: I studied this at college, university. I studied art, design, animation and games. I come to this website is for look on questions and answered.
Gagantous, you're just fans. You don't how long and low many an artist have studied.

Comment: i would have to disagree with the part about it being hard to script A+/A- in games, infarct it's very easy since in real life the F-A rating is (from my experience) represented from a percentage value as such any rating system can be scripted if you have a numerical amount to base it in, for instance *The Legend of Heroes: Trails in the Sky SC* uses G-A ranking with + in between them (ie. G, G+, F, F+, E, etc) for your Bracer Rank which is calculated by your BP Total

Comment: I remember I learned about this game s-ranking system, but I don't remember who is the author of making this system, sorry. I remember have origin author/developer who make this, but not remember the name of author and company name, this is minor title in history.

Comment: I agree your disagreement Memor-X. Because I'm not explained all game ranking system, because it's too many. Developers have ideas what should need to put in, there was no right and wrong. If you have played Harry Potter java version, then you see O,A,E,T, O is Outstanding, A is Acceptable, E is Exception, T is Troll. Base on ideas, creative thinking. Author can create a new ranks by ideas. They all have own meanings. Major game have Gaming ESRB rating system is E is Everyone, T is Teen, M is Mature. Actually, Rank G and X is existed in the reality too.

Answer (score -5):

R = "rare", aka D-f
SR = "super rare", aka C
SSR = "super,super rare", aka B
UR = "ultimate rare", aka A
TUR = "transcended UR", aka A+
LR = "limited rare", aka A++

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question. *Why* are these rankings used? Why not just use A-F? Also, I can't say I've ever seen "TUR" or "LR" - can you provide some sort of evidence that these are actually used in the way you've suggested?